# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 127.0.0.1 - Windows 32 bits - Node v6.11.2

Tags: node.js, windows, 32-bit

I'm launching a server with the following script (arranca_server.sh)

```
# Arranca servidor Node
export NODE_ENV=development-curso
export NODE_PORT=9001
export NODE_HOST=127.0.0.1
node server
```

And Node returns:

```
>     events.js:160
>           throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>           ^
>     
>     Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 127.0.0.1
>         at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
>         at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

---

Node version:

```
$ node -v
v6.11.2
```

> S.O. Windows 7 32 bits

---

What have I tried?

1. Differents NODE_HOST like: localhost, 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, computer_name, empty, ::1, computer_ip and others...
2. Differents NODE_PORT like: 9001, 12001, 30001, ...
3. Adding `127.0.0.1 localhost` in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a local firewall enabled? Have you added a rule to allow Node JS to open ports?

Comment: I added a rule for port 9001 but it does not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

In my case I have solved it by changing my file *arranca_server.sh*

```
# Arranca servidor Node
export NODE_ENV=development-curso
export NODE_PORT=9001
export NODE_HOST=127.0.0.1
node server
```

by this other *arranca_server.bat*

```
# Arranca servidor Node
SET NODE_ENV=development-curso
SET NODE_PORT=9001
SET NODE_HOST=127.0.0.1
node server
```

Comment: Glad you solved, however, strange that `export` didn't work, it should make the variable available for any of the child processes.